# Create an ad unit using Google Ad Manager API

Tags: php, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to use the API to create an ad unit, but I can't figure out how to set the "TV app name" field, I tried looking online and in the documentation but haven't found something helpful, can someone please help?

this is my code, I need to use the "TV app name" to set "This is TV inventory" and then select the app name from the list (which we will get from an function argument). this is the code I'm using (which creates an ad unit):

```
<?php
namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdManager\v202305\InventoryService;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\AdManagerSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\AdManagerSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\AdUnit;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\AdUnitSize;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\AdUnitTargetWindow;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\EnvironmentType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\ServiceFactory;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\Size;
use Google\AdsApi\AdManager\v202305\tname;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

class CreateAdUnits
{

    public static function runExample(
        ServiceFactory $serviceFactory,
        AdManagerSession $session
    ) {
        $inventoryService = $serviceFactory->createInventoryService($session);
        $networkService = $serviceFactory->createNetworkService($session);
        $network = $networkService->getCurrentNetwork();
        $effectiveRootAdUnitId = $network->getEffectiveRootAdUnitId();

        // Configure the ad unit to be created.
        $adUnit = new AdUnit();
        $adUnit->setName('test');
        $adUnit->setParentId('22937222828');
        $adUnit->setAdUnitCode('test');
        $adUnit->setDescription('Banner ad on a sports page.');
        $adUnit->setTargetWindow(AdUnitTargetWindow::BLANK);

        // Set the size of possible creatives that can match this ad unit.
        $size = new Size();
        $size->setWidth(1920);
        $size->setHeight(1080);
        $size->setIsAspectRatio(false);
        $adUnitSize = new AdUnitSize();
        $adUnitSize->setSize($size);
        $adUnitSize->setEnvironmentType(EnvironmentType::BROWSER);
        $adUnit->setAdUnitSizes([$adUnitSize]);

        // Create the ad units on the server.
        $adUnits = $inventoryService->createAdUnits([$adUnit]);

        // Print out some information for each created ad unit.
        foreach ($adUnits as $i => $adUnit) {
            printf(
                "%d) An ad unit with ID '%s' and name '%s' was created.%s",
                $i,
                $adUnit->getId(),
                $adUnit->getName(),
                PHP_EOL
            );
        }

        printf("Created %d ad unit(s).%s", count($adUnits), PHP_EOL);
    }

    public static function main()
    {
        // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()
            ->build();

        // Construct an API session configured from an `adsapi_php.ini` file
        // and the OAuth2 credentials above.
        $session = (new AdManagerSessionBuilder())->fromFile()
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            ->build();

        self::runExample(new ServiceFactory(), $session);
    }
}

CreateAdUnits::main();
```

Comment: can someone help with this?